# Promise from aggregate() and find() with MongoDB driver for NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

I head and always read that MongoDB driver (>2.0) for NodeJS supports promises. But the only examples I find are with the connect() and findOne() functions. While it works for those and I can get promises, it doesn't with aggregate() nor with find(). I get that's because they might be returning cursors, but since there is promise support, where are those promises? There must be a way to work with them. A link, an example or simple explanation would be so welcome :)

Thank you,
Jordy.

Comment: Because `.find()` and `.aggregate()` return a [`Cursor`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html), (technically`.aggregate()` is a "little" different)  which is really an augmented form of a node stream. If you want data you can resolve with a Promise then you want something like [`.toArray()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#toArray). The point is the "default" `Cursor` is for "large" results, where you can "optionally" go small with an "array" structure. Things like mongoose do this for you "automagically".

Comment: Thank you @NeilLunn, that is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chain the result from `find()` or `aggregate()` to `.toArray()`. The documentation of `toArray` for the current mongodb nodejs driver is [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#toArray).

Comment: You can also try using aggregate().exec() which will return a promise

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is write your own custom promise function such as:

```
Query.prototype.find = function (callback) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.model.find(this.query).skip(this.skip).limit(this.limit).sort(this.sort).exec((err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            return reject(err);
        }

        return resolve({ find: results });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: The [native node driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/) does not have an `.exec()` method. You looked up [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) which is different from the plain native driver.